# Sublime Text 2 How to disable *.lib extension file filetering

Tags: sublimetext2

ST2 seems to automatically filter out files with **.lib** extension in **Goto Anything...**, probably a default setting for filtering binary files. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could edit this, or better yet, edit it in your `Settings-User` file.

```
// folder_exclude_patterns and file_exclude_patterns control which files
// are listed in folders on the side bar. These can also be set on a per-
// project basis.
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"],
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", ........
```

Located:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed **.lib** in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings.